# no module named 'Elasticsearch ' jupyter

Tags: elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook

I' m trying to use elasticsearch  with jupyter notebook   I have installed elasticsearch python client using  `pip install elasticsearch`  and I have included the elasticsearch spark connector jar on the classpath when launching my notebook but when I tested if elasticsearch instance is running I got  `No Module named elasticsearch` here is the code that I used :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
es=Elasticsearch()
es.info(pretty=True)
```

and this is what I see in elasticsearch server :
[image]

Comment: Can you share what you see in the logs of your Elasticsearch server?

Comment: yes , I share it

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get the Elasticsearch Python library to import into Python using the `pip install elasticsearch` method. I had to do `conda install elasticsearch -y` to get the Jupyter Notebook to be able to import it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I took when I found the same error in my Mac upon installing elasticsearch using

```
brew tap elastic/tap   
brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

and then in python using

```
!conda install elasticsearch -y
```

Eventually I figured out my python site-package location using following commands inside python shell

```
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> print(get_python_lib())
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Eventually I added following line in the end of my `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PYTHONPATH=/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

and executed it using `. ~/.bash_profile`
(If just executing it doesn't work, consider restarting your PC/Mac)

This allowed me to run following import

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
```

P.S : If somehow you find elasticsearch listner isn't running, consider running it from 
`$ES_HOME/bin` by running `.$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch`

Answer (score 0):

@Jon 's answer might work but probably it's not the most correct way to do it. If it works, it's probable that you're using virtual envs with conda, so be sure to first activate the venv you're working on with `source activate <venv name>` and then you should be able to run `pip install elasticsearch` without any problem.